# How do I disable zsh autocompletion for svn

Tags: svn, zsh

My svn is really slow at work and I don't want zsh to try and autocomplete using any svn info. How do I stop it from doing that?

The relevant bit in my .zshrc looks like this:

```
autoload -U compinit ; compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "$LS_COLORS"
zstyle '*:my-accounts' users-hosts $my_accounts

setopt \
no_nomatch \
hist_ignore_all_dups \
hist_reduce_blanks \
hist_no_store \
long_list_jobs \
rm_star_silent
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been running into this same issue with really slow completion with svn. Today I finally stumbled across the answer:

Add this to your .zshrc (you can also run this on in the shell): `compdef -d svn`